# any one aware of playwright integration with openfin?

Tags: javascript, playwright, openfin

any one aware of playwright integration with openfin? I am stuck at how to intiate OpenFin via playwright as an exe or url ? Any samples or examples might help.

Expecting to integrate

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example repo that runs a collection of Playwright tests against `Hello OpenFin` - an example OpenFin app - [Github Repo](https://github.com/chuck-adaptive/lets-playwright)

The key piece of logic is here - [creating a Browser fixture that connects to OpenFin](https://github.com/chuck-adaptive/lets-playwright/blob/main/fixtures.ts#L31). Some automation tools require you to launch an approved binary. In this case, we start the Runtime binary and then connect to it via the Chrome Devtools Port. The fixtures then work from that connection, where you can discover your application windows. This is in scope for that repo.

Note that `RUNTIME_ADDRESS` [link](https://github.com/chuck-adaptive/lets-playwright/blob/main/fixtures.ts#L18) and the `devtools_port` in the `app.json` [link](https://github.com/chuck-adaptive/lets-playwright/blob/main/hello-openfin.app.json#L2) are the same (the app.json number referes to a localhost port). This is required for connection.

You could start OpenFin before and after the suite just leveraging Node to start the Runtime, and closing all Windows via Playwright to stop it.

Edit: For reference I am the author of the repository and put it together as a proof of concept some time ago.

If this is not the part of your automation you want to focus on, you may want to consider Selenium. There is a new set of OpenFin automation tools [@openfin/automation-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@openfin/automation-cli), [@openfin-automation/helpers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@openfin/automation-helpers), [@openfin/automation-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@openfin/automation-native), which provide some WebDriver locators for various elements out of the box